# Comparison of key press and string

Tags: javascript

I am doing an experiment and I want a part to be shown if a certain key ("b") is pressed and skipped, if any other key is pressed. The key that is pressed is saved in key_resp_3.keys and if I visualize what's saved in the key_resp_3.keys variable it's simply b.
So I thought this would be the right comparison:

```
    if ((key_resp_3.keys != "b")) {
        continueRoutine = false;
    }
```

However in this case, the routine is always skipped so somehow "b" is obviously not the way the key is saved in the key_resp_3.keys variable. Does anyone have an idea what is the right comparison instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Try logging the variable to the console to make sure what its value is; ```console.log( key_resp_3.keys )```. Also, your current code seems to stop execution whenever the variable is NOT ```"b"```, isn't that the inverse of what you want? Check out the [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) section, and read up on what ```!=``` means.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistakte in the upper description, I want the part to be shown, when b is pressed and to be skipped when any other key is pressed.

Comment: Try and set `continueRoutine` manually outside the condition and see if it is affecting the routine.

Comment: @AlainDoe Array [ "b" ] is the value. However, I am not sure how to ask for it in the comparison operator...

Comment: If it's an Array and you need to find out if ```"b"``` is inside of it, you can use [.indexOf( )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Example comparison to see if ```b``` is not apart of the Array; ; ```if ( key_resp_3.keys.indexOf("b") < 0 ){``` . ```indexOf``` will return ```-1``` if the value is not inside of the array, and the first found index if it is, starting at ```0```.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell the root cause of the problem without the rest of the code. But you can simply use an event listener like below

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log(event.key)
    
    const key = event.key
    if(key == "b")
      alert("b presed")    
});
```

Or can it be as simple as you are trying to set `const key_resp_3 = event.key` then checking in the if `key_resp_3.keys` so you are trying to access `variable.key.key`

**In this special case:**
since the `keys` is a array you can use

```
Does contains b
key_resp_3.keys.includes('b')

Does not contains b
!key_resp_3.keys.includes('b')
```

Comment: Here is the full code (l. 2189): https://gitlab.pavlovia.org/Sandra.Tyralla/2021_mg_expra_ldt/blob/master/untitled.js

Comment: @LindaEspey you can probably use !keys.includes("b") instead of key_resp_3.keys != "b"